# Is it possible to condense 2 blocks of code into one line lambda?

Tags: python

Here are scores for some students

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[71,62,13], [75,76,77]], columns=list("ABC"))
df
```

[image]

## example_1

The scores that are lower than 60 need to be marked red and here is a possible approach.

```
def highlight_cell(c):
    if c < 60:
        color = 'color:red;'
    else:
        color = ''
    return color
df.style.apply(lambda x: [highlight_cell(c) for c in x])
```

[image]

The code above could be condensed to just one line

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: ["color: red" if c < 60 else '' for c in x])
```

## example_2

In a similar fashion, consider this code

```
def highlight_cell(c):
    print(c)
    if c < 60:
        color = 'color:red;'
    else:
        color = ''
    return color
df.style.apply(lambda x: [highlight_cell(c) for c in x])
```

adding just one more print to trace the processing order of elements.

Is it possible to condense this code into one line, as example_1?

Comment: Only through trickery:  `df.style.apply(lambda x: [(print(c) or "color: red") if c < 60 else '' for c in x])`.  That works because `print` returns None, so it always takes the other `or` clause.

Comment: compressing to one line make it less readable - and worst for `tracing` problems - so better keep it as normal function.